# How to require a Ruby gem directly from its path?

Tags: ruby, rubygems, zip

In order to work with rubyzip i installed the gems:

```
gem install --local rubyzip-1.1.7.gem  
gem install --local zip-zip-0.3.gem
```

In my code i call the gems using the require method:

```
  require 'zip/zip' 
  require 'zip/filesystem'
```

I want  to use require to load the gems directly from their location on my machine.

i want somthing like this:

```
 require 'path_to_my_zip_gem'
```

Where path_to_my zip_gem contains the gem files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, it's because `require` method loads files by name from paths listed in `$:` or `$LOAD_PATH`

> "If the filename does not resolve to an absolute path, it will be
>   searched for in the directories listed in $LOAD_PATH ($:)."
>
> http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/Kernel.html#method-i-require

If you want to require a gem from the "local" path then the `require_relative` method could help since you can specify a path relative to the requiring file’s path. Look at the official documentation for further details:

http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/Kernel.html#method-i-require_relative

Answer (score 1):

The simpliest answer is

```
Gem::Specification.find_by_name("GEM_NAME_HERE").full_gem_path
```

Example

```
> require File.join(Gem::Specification.find_by_name("railties").full_gem_path, "lib/rails/code_statistics.rb")
=> true
```