# How to require ruby gem from a specific location?

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I am new to ruby, and is trying to write a git hook in ruby. I want to use the rugged gem in my script. The gem is already available in `/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gem/ruby/2.1.0/` as part of GitLab installation ([Files List](http://pastebin.com/Rc1NcbVZ)). How can I require that gem in my script?

I have tried `$LOAD_PATH.unshift "/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gem/ruby/2.1.0/"` and then `require "rugged"`, as mentioned in [another stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30187990/how-to-require-a-ruby-gem-directly-from-its-path), but it did not work.

Comment: Are you using [Bundler](http://bundler.io)? Usually it handles this stuff for you.

Comment: I am using bundler for other required gems. But installing the `rugged` gem requires installation of `gcc` and `cmake`. So I wanted to load it from the existing installation location.

Comment: If it has compiled extensions you'll have to compile it on that machine. It's very risky to throw binaries onto arbitrary machines, they're often locked to particular versions of system libraries. Getting `gcc` and such on there shouldn't be hard, right? If you're manipulating the load path you must include the parent directory of that gem, not just where all gems are located.

Comment: The gem is already installed and used by GitLab. I have included the list of files in the question. Can you please tell me which directory I have to add to $LOAD_PATH? Installing `gcc` is definitely  a possible solution, I am just using this as a learning opportunity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look carefully at how `$LOAD_PATH` is configured for each `gem` after you include it. Normally it's the full path to where the base `gemname.rb` is located, like in your case where `rugged.rb` is.

The way the `$LOAD_PATH` works is it scans through that list looking for `rugged.rb` and if it doesn't find it, moves on to the next possible location. You're specifying a directory which doesn't have that, so find the right path and fill that in, and you should be good.

Comment: Thank you. I used `$LOAD_PATH.unshift "/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gem/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rugged-0.24.0/lib/"` and  it worked.

Comment: That's roughly it, but keep in mind this is usually a lot messier than using Bundler. It just occurred to me that you might have a way of doing this more cleanly using the Bundler `:path` option: `gem 'rugged', path: '/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gem/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rugged-0.24.0/'` Unfortunately that makes your `Gemfile` locked to a particular machine which is usually a bad thing.

Comment: I had to use `gem "rugged", path: '/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gem/ruby/2.1.0/'` and bundle install completed successfully with message that it will be using 'rugged' from the specified path. But when I run `bundle exec ./update.rb`, it fails unable to find the gem.

Comment: Sounds like you need to use the same full path there, then. Whatever works.

Comment: That did not work. This is the only path it accepted. Other paths failed with message `Could not find gem 'rugged (>= 0) ruby' in source at <path>`. When I use the above path, `bundle list` is showing the correct version of rugged. It is just that it is not available when I execute the file.

Comment: `bundle check` is happy or no? Usually it gets upset if the location is missing a `.gemspec` file.

Comment: `bundle check` gives `The Gemfile's dependencies are satisfied`

Comment: This is odd. Ideally you can do a clean install with `bundle install` and avoid all the path nonsense, but if you can find a solution that works with manipulating `$LOAD_PATH` that could be a good temporary fix.

Comment: `Bundler.require` within `irb` gives `=> [<Bundler::Dependency type=:runtime name="rugged" requirements="= 0.24.0">, <Bundler::Dependency type=:runtime name="net-ssh" requirements="= 3.1.1">, <Bundler::Dependency type=:runtime name="colorize" requirements="= 0.7.7">]`. But when I try to use the `Rugged` class, I am getting the error `uninitialized constant Rugged`